# Where can I find csv or json data on absolute global average temperature

Tags: temperature, climate-models

I am essentially looking for a list of raw datasets without any processing. I can find anomaly datasets, but have had no luck with 100% unprocessed (other than averaging, of course) data. This data is preferably monthly (or less) averaged but it doesn't make that much of a difference to me.

Comment: Check [this](https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/)

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego thank you, this will help

Comment: I'm not sure how one can have "global average temperature" without any processing?

Comment: @SemidiurnalSimon If you are saying that averaging is processing, I mentioned that above "(other than averaging, of course)"

Comment: So you did. My apologies!

Comment: @SemidiurnalSimon no problem :)